# YouTube API 2.0 resumable upload - error 500

Tags: ios, upload, youtube-api

I'm using YouTube API 2.0 in iOS app and I have made request like this:

```
POST http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads

Authorization = "Bearer <acess_token>";
"Content-Length" = 516;
"Content-Type" = "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8";
"GData-Version" = 2;
Slug = "testVideo.mov";
"X-GData-Key" = "key=<api_key>";
```

with body:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
<media:group>
<media:title type="plain">My title</media:title>
<media:description type="plain">My description</media:description>
<media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">Entertainment</media:category>
<media:keywords>mediawork</media:keywords>
</media:group>
</entry>
```

But the server response was with error 500 and no XML body with explanatoin. What should I do? It worked a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this issue. But per our [blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html), Stack Overflow prides itself in being a destination for questions and answers, and not a place to file bug reports or feature requests. We ask that developers do not post on Stack Overflow for those sorts of things, and instead make use of the templates we have for [filing a bug](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Defect%20Report%29) or [filing a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Enhancement%20Request%29) in our existing public issue tracker. (Be sure to check the [list of existing open issues](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label%3aAPI-YouTube) before filing a duplicate.)

This issue is already reported https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4396
You can track the status from there.